# Docker error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: bbfec3f85216: permission denied

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and I tried removing the container and its showing the error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
docker container stop <container name>
```

and after that kill it

Comment: `docker kill` [description](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/): Kill one or more *running* containers

Answer (score 0):

You [need to add user to `docker` group](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E75728/html/section_rdz_hmw_2q.html) to grant container management permissions:

```
groupadd docker
usermod -a -G docker omsairam
```